# Gnome3 custom shortcuts don't work

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

I have a clean install of 16.04 with the ubuntu gnome packages installed.
I can use the shortcuts tab of the keyboard setting to set keybindings for built-in gnome functions (such as "Launch help browser") but custom shortcuts don't work.

Even when I try to allocate something really simple like "gnome-terminal" or "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal" as a command the shortcut does not activate.
I'm using really simple shortcuts like <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to test, but it can't be that anyway because the shortcuts work for built-in functions.

To be clear I am attempting to do this in:
Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut tab -> Custom shortcuts (bottom left).

I'm going out of my mind trying to do something this simple!
At one point I thought of setting up custom shortcuts in ccsm, but gnome3 does not use compiz.
If anyone has any suggestions (or workarounds) I would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE 09NOV2016**
Looks like it is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1224732) with Gnome Classic (I guess most classic people just use Mate? Anyway I've just switched to use xbindkeys).

Comment: I use gnome3 shortcuts everywhere with no problems (debian,fedora,etc). Just for checking try a diff key (example the tradicional CTR+ALT+T) and `gnome-terminal --window`

Comment: I did try many key combinations! And as I said above it _can't_ be the key combinations that I picked anyway because all of them work perfectly when assigned to gnome functions.

Comment: I can confirm this is a problem for gnome-desktop installed on regular Ubuntu 16.04. Custom keyboard shortcuts work fine in Unity, but not at all in Gnome.

Comment: I also can confirm this bug.